# Duplicate row if a column contains any special character in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a small python program to deal with orders I receive. But due to change in the reference value I used to merge my df on is changed.

Example:

[image: Data]

The problem is, I used to merge Old PO numbers to new PO numbers so that I know a customer is returning. But recently I started receiving partial orders which are 3c456 instead of 3c456/4c345. It means my customer is renewing only one product now. 
My pd.merge code doesn't find the partial order anymore.

My code was

```
df = pd.merge(old_PO_file, New_PO_file, on =PO-number)
```

since the new PO is partial and could be the value before or after the slash.
**I would like to duplicate all the rows in PO-number column if there is a Slash(/) in that cell**.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code in question

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Just added the code. It used to be a simple pd.merge code.

Comment: So you want to make the `3c456/4c345` row into two rows a `3c456` row and a  `4c345` row?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series` for [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
   Sold-to    PO-Number Sold-to-party
0     1234       6d1234   abc company
1     2345  3c456/4c345   edf company
2     5679        9f639   mno company

df1 = df.drop('PO-Number', axis=1) \
        .join(df['PO-Number'] \
        .str \
        .split('/', expand=True) \
        .stack() \
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('PO-Number')) \
        .reset_index(drop=True)

print (df1)
   Sold-to Sold-to-party PO-Number
0     1234   abc company    6d1234
1     2345   edf company     3c456
2     2345   edf company     4c345
3     5679   mno company     9f639
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Though, I will take a lot of time in understanding how you did it.... Thank you